# Difference between Serialization in [KnownType] and [XmlInclude]

Tags: wcf

I have few WCF data contracts as following:

```
        [DataContract] 
        public class Hatchback: Car
        {
            [DataMember]   
            public int Wheels;
        } 

        [KnownType(Hatchback)] 
        [DataContract] 
        public abstract class Car
        {

        }
```

I can also write this as following:

```
        [DataContract] 
        public class Hatchback: Car
        {
            [DataMember]   
            public int Wheels;
        } 

        [XmlInclude(Hatchback)] 
        [DataContract] 
        public abstract class Car
        {

        }
```

What is the differnece between this two different type of implementations? Is there any advantage/disadvantages of XmlInclude over KnownType?

Answer (score 6):

XmlIncludeAttribute is usually used for serialization/deserialization with XmlSerializer and KnownTypeAtrribute is used for DataContractSerializer.

These 2 attributes are for the same purpose --- Specifies types that should be recognized by the XmlSerializer/DataContractSerializer when serializing or deserializing a given type.